# What component values could be deduced from this graph? It is for a restricted DC motor, A vs T

Tags: dc-motor

[image]

What components cause this graph to look like this, what values could they be given? the DC motor has a P magnet and a split ring commutator and is powered by 9V supply. Why did current take time to reach final value? The motor was restricted from moving ( like a high load) at power up.

Answer (score 3):

As Marko alluded to, this is the R-L of the stator.

There is enough information present to estimate the values

**Determining R**

The resistive component can be deduced once steady-state has been reached. Looking at the graph, the steady-state current is ~3A.

Via Ohm's law and a voltage source of 9V, the resistance is ~ 3Ohms

**Determining L**

The time constant of an RL network is L/R and is the time it takes to reach ~63% of the final value.

With the final value being 3A, 63% is ~1.9A and this occurs ~ 1100ms

With an estimated R know and an estimated \$\tau\$ known, an estimated L can be determined ~ 2.08H

Answer (score 1):

It's a time constant L/R . Inductance and resistance are playing the key role, here.

$$I= \dfrac{V}{R} \cdot(1- e^{-\dfrac{L}{R}t}) $$